# Difference between runtime and syntax error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error, scanf

I have a problem like this:

> Q. Pick ANY error you can have from here:
>
> ```
> int main(void)
> {
>     int a;
>
>     printf("Input a integer number >>");
>     scanf("%d\n", a);
>     printf("The input number is %d\n", a);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> 1. syntax error
> 2. logical error
> 3. run-time error
> 4. no error

I thought it was both syntax and run-time error because:

- For syntax, there is no `&` in front of `a`.
- For run-time error, the program would still be built to run the first print statement and suddenly stop at `scanf()` statement because there is no `&`.

However, I was told that I'm wrong.

I know that it is not logical error, but I'm confused which one is which.

Answer (score 1):

No, there will not be any syntax error here, only run-time error.

`scanf()` expects a pointer to the variable to store the value but that does not mandate that we have to use the `&` operator always to pass an address.

Imagine, in case `a` would have been a pointer (and allocated proper memory),

```
scanf("%d\n", a);
```

would have been a perfectly valid statement, isn't it?

In this code, you have passed the *value* of an uninitialized variable (*which get tread as an address, which will be invalid*) as an argument to the `%d` format specifier to `scanf()`, so that invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) that causes runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax errors are detected by compiler. This program compiles fine, so it does not have syntax errors.

However, this program passes the value of an *uninitialized* variable `a` to `scanf`, which is undefined behavior, i.e. a runtime error.